# Use remote profile from remote machine with selenium java

Tags: profile

)
On my work I faced with trouble how to test extension on remote browsers? Extension install from .exe file that close all open browsers. I need to test extension in all browsers so if i open new chromeDriver or even firefoxDriver session it begins anonym session so i can't test if extension installed properly or not. I tried

```
    File fp = new File("C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Roaming\\Mozilla\\Firefox\\Profiles\\ojt048j5.default");
    FirefoxProfile ffProfile = new FirefoxProfile(fp);

    DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
    capability.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, ffProfile);
    capability.setBrowserName("firefox");
    URL hostURL = new URL("http://" + machine.getIp() + ":4444/wd/hub");
    WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(hostURL, capability);
    driver.get("http://www.google.com")
```

code above uses firefox profile from my host machine but not from Remote

Is there any sugestion how can I test it?

Answer (score 0):

I found answer with using ftp. You can download remote profile folder whih ftp?, use it to set browser profile(on host machine), and delete profile folder after browser starts. More detail you can find on this site:

http://www.codejava.net/java-se/networking/ftp/how-to-download-a-complete-folder-from-a-ftp-server

To download whole folder use mkdirs() instead of mkdir() (used in FTPUtil > downloadSingleFile)